# Sent/Received message counters on Careers are wrong?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I've logged in to Careers today and the sent/received counters for messages from employers seem to be wrong. I've got 4/4, but I'm sure it was 4/5 yesterday. Here's my inbox:

[image]

If you add the counters next to each thread you get 9 messages in total, yet only 8 seem to be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers represent the number of threads you have, not a total message count.

Comment: So the meaning has changed in the meantime? Because I'm pretty sure until recently it was total number of individual messages exchanged.

Comment: @Tudor: Yes it was. We always meant it to be what it is now, but we had a bug. We fixed it a couple days ago.

Comment: @Jason Punyon: Alright then, thanks.